# Unknown folders that are seen on Windows from Ubuntu

Tags: windows, nautilus, gnome-terminal, directory

Inside a folder on Windows can be seen its content from Nautilus as shown in the image:

[image: View of Folder from Nautilus]

Its contents as seen from terminal:

[image: View of Folder from Terminal]

On whatever folder can be found other folders with the name `.` and `..` only from terminal. What kind of folders are these? Is it something to worry about? I can't see inside of these folders neither from Terminal nor from Nautilus.

Comment: Possible duplicate : [What are ./ and ../ directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63081/what-are-and-directories)

Answer (score 2):

No need to worry. This is system names related to current folder and parent folder.
. - current
.. - parent
Its used to go to parent directory: `cd ..`
Current used to make relative path as example `./somescript.sh` (since current folder not in `PATH`)